# Online Classroom: VSat, Leased line or something else?

Tags: networking, video-streaming

One of my friends is planning to set up a online classroom sort of environment and currently is evaluating the various ISP/Connection options he can have. Though he certainly needs a 100% up time of the internet connection, it can be compromised to like 99.X% for a good internet speed. Also since he is just starting up, 'price' too is a constraint but quality should not be compromised.

VSat link is one of the options that we know that might work out but I am very confused googling on the benifts of a VSat link as compared to a leased line. I feel a 2 MBPS leased line(may be 2) can suffice.

What should be the right connection? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSat is going to have a noticeable delay if you're doing anything interactive. It's also prone to weather (heavy storms, snow, can affect the quality of the link). Also, are you in a remote area or a developing country? If you're not, then you should just go with some business DSL line.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. No, this person is going to be operational from a metro city. Forgive my ignorance but over a Business DSL line won't a leased line be better(a bit costly though)?